# Get a fully-qualified URL in Visualforce and Communities/Sites

Tags: visualforce

I'm doing an integration that involves passing fully qualified URLs to another application as form inputs so that they can be used for a callback.  The URL is for another Visualforce page (not a webservice).  For example, a form might look something like this:

```
<form action="https://myformaction">
    <input type="hidden" name="callbackUrl" value="URL-GOES-HERE"/>
    <!-- rest of the form -->
</form>
```

I'm having trouble getting a valid, fully qualified URL to show up.  Here's what I've tried:

1. `{!URLFOR($Page.PageName)}` ==> `/siteprefix/PageName`, which doesn't work because it's a relative URL, so the external service can't redirect to it.
2. `{!$Site.CurrentSiteUrl}{!URLFOR($Page.PageName)}` ==> `https://salesforce.domain/siteprefix//siteprefix/PageName`, which doesn't work because the siteprefix is included twice, and there's a double `//`
3. `https://{!$Site.Domain}{!URLFOR($Page.PageName)}` ==> `https://salesforce.domain/siteprefix/PageName`, which works for now - but I'm worried it will break when we switch to a custom domain down the line.

I've run into the same problem when trying to include links in Visualforce email templates, where the `$Site` variable isn't available.  Am I missing something?  Seems like this should be a simple thing to do...

Answer (score 6):

I just heard from someone at Salesforce that for Visualforce pages, this solution should work even with custom domains:

```
https://{!$Site.Domain}{!URLFOR($Page.PageName)}
```

However, that doesn't solve the problem for email templates.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using `URL.getCurrentRequestUrl()` (as documented in http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_url.htm) then using String manipulation to build the URL that I want and exposing that through a Custom Controller/Controller Extension for similar functionality.

The issues with this are:

- doesn't work with `@future` annotated methods (I need to query for the Site that I'm operating in)
- won't work for your email case.